# Que change l'utilisation de « vos » ou « votre » lorsqu'on s'adresse à plusieurs personnes ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, possessif

Imaginons un professeur rendant des rédactions à ses élèves, et leur demandant de les corriger pour le lendemain. Dira-t-il en s'adressant aux élèves:

> Corrigez vos rédactions pour demain.

ou

> Corrigez votre rédaction pour demain.

Les deux formes me semblent acceptables mais l'une d'entre elle est-elle préférable grammaticalement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

S'il n'y a qu'une seule rédaction par élève :

- Dans le premier cas, le professeur s'adresse à la classe.
- Dans le second, il adresse un message collectif que chaque élève entend individuellement.